# Rails Tutorial Error With Cloud 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide

Trying to get this to work, but I'm having trouble. I'm following the instructions at:
https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#cha-beginning

I get to 1.3.2 and I type:

```
rails server -b $IP -p $PORT
```

Which results in this error instead of WEBrick running:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:11:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Sass::Script (NameError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello_app/bin/rails:8:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello_app/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello_app/bin/spring:13:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello_app/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

This seems to only happen when you replace the Gemfile code with the code specified to get the explicit version of Ruby gems (the code below).

source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails',                '4.2.0'
gem 'sass-rails',           '5.0.1'
gem 'uglifier',             '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',         '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',         '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',           '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',             '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                 '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Looks like the tutorial has just recently  fallen out of date. If you update your gemfile from

```
gem 'sass-rails',           '5.0.1'
```

to

```
gem 'sass-rails',           '5.0.2'
```

then bundle install again and launch the server, it should work just fine.

(If you prefer, you can also run a workaround by adding

```
gem 'sass', '3.4.13'
```

before your existing, non-updated line:

```
gem 'sass-rails',           '5.0.1'
```

in your gemfile, and doing a bundle install and launching the server. I don't know why you'd need to, though.)

Comment: The tutorial had already been updated with a fix (adding `gem 'sass'` to the Gemfile), but this solution is better. It's now been added to the tutorial. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, it's not quite right that "the tutorial has just recently fallen out of date". A more accurate description is "someone involved in the Sass gem or another part of the Ruby ecosystem made a change that shouldn't have broken anything anywhere, but did." Alas, this is par for the course in Ruby-land—perhaps the price we pay for always [moving so fast](http://startupquote.com/post/1624569753).

Comment: @Blobert You should select this answer as the correct answer.