# Application error heroku, ruby on rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am following the ruby on rails tutorial(recomended here on stack:) ) Loved it so far but i can't seem to deploy my application via heroku. Can someone give me light on what to do?

```
2015-07-23T23:46:37.387879+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-07-23T23:46:37.390702+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-07-23T23:46:38.056116+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/?_c9_id=livepreview7&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io" host=vast-shore-9845.herokuapp.com request_id=9bc94d44-685f-4554-9940-fe01f5f8acfc fwd="84.81.77.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-07-23T23:47:04.275534+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
2015-07-23T23:47:04.275511+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-07-23T23:47:34.243854+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-07-23T23:47:34.243873+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
2015-07-23T23:47:48.259354+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/?_c9_id=livepreview7&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io" host=vast-shore-9845.herokuapp.com request_id=80c80609-252a-4603-adc1-ef8fd3803675 fwd="84.81.77.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-07-23T23:50:42.867239+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-07-23T23:50:42.867266+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
2015-07-23T23:53:02.818263+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-07-23T23:53:02.818432+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-07-23T23:53:02.741040+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy cb3c9d8 by 
2015-07-23T23:53:02.741040+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by 
2015-07-23T23:53:02.845508+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-07-23T23:53:07.556502+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 10779 -e production`
2015-07-23T23:53:11.732808+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:11:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Sass::Script (NameError)
2015-07-23T23:53:11.732845+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-23T23:53:11.732841+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `require'
2015-07-23T23:53:11.732848+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-23T23:53:11.732853+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
2015-07-23T23:53:11.732847+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
2015-07-23T23:53:11.732850+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
2015-07-23T23:53:11.732854+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
2015-07-23T23:53:11.732856+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
2015-07-23T23:53:11.732857+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
2015-07-23T23:53:11.732864+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
2015-07-23T23:53:11.732880+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-07-23T23:53:11.732878+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
2015-07-23T23:53:11.732867+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
2015-07-23T23:53:11.732859+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
2015-07-23T23:53:11.732865+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-23T23:53:11.732881+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-07-23T23:53:11.732882+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-07-23T23:53:11.732884+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-23T23:53:11.732885+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-07-23T23:53:11.732886+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-07-23T23:53:12.670912+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-07-23T23:53:12.675113+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-07-23T23:53:26.378922+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vast-shore-9845.herokuapp.com request_id=fcb97d6f-128b-4d2b-b3e8-c2de87eb7e33 fwd="84.81.77.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-07-23T23:53:25.583623+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vast-shore-9845.herokuapp.com request_id=00322a0d-ad99-43c9-8c40-090c0459cfba fwd="84.81.77.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-07-23T23:59:48.868798+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-07-23T23:59:48.868814+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-07-23T23:59:48.811695+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy d7257fd by 
2015-07-23T23:59:48.811695+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by 
2015-07-23T23:59:48.962017+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-07-23T23:59:53.564068+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 45661`
2015-07-23T23:59:56.828404+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:11:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Sass::Script (NameError)
2015-07-23T23:59:56.828424+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `require'
2015-07-23T23:59:56.828426+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-23T23:59:56.828428+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
2015-07-23T23:59:56.828429+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-23T23:59:56.828431+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
2015-07-23T23:59:56.828435+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
2015-07-23T23:59:56.828437+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
2015-07-23T23:59:56.828438+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
2015-07-23T23:59:56.828440+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
2015-07-23T23:59:56.828441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
2015-07-23T23:59:56.828442+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
2015-07-23T23:59:56.828444+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-23T23:59:56.828445+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
2015-07-23T23:59:56.828447+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
2015-07-23T23:59:56.828448+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-07-23T23:59:56.828449+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-07-23T23:59:56.828450+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-07-23T23:59:56.828452+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-23T23:59:56.828453+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-07-23T23:59:56.828457+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-07-23T23:59:57.609465+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-07-23T23:59:57.597734+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-07-23T23:59:57.610775+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-07-24T00:00:00.487775+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 28996`
2015-07-24T00:00:03.609964+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:11:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Sass::Script (NameError)
2015-07-24T00:00:03.609994+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `require'
2015-07-24T00:00:03.609997+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-24T00:00:03.609998+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
2015-07-24T00:00:03.610000+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-24T00:00:03.610001+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
2015-07-24T00:00:03.610003+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
2015-07-24T00:00:03.610004+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
2015-07-24T00:00:03.610009+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
2015-07-24T00:00:03.610010+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
2015-07-24T00:00:03.610012+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
2015-07-24T00:00:03.610013+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
2015-07-24T00:00:03.610014+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-24T00:00:03.610016+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
2015-07-24T00:00:03.610017+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
2015-07-24T00:00:03.610019+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-07-24T00:00:03.610020+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-07-24T00:00:03.610021+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-07-24T00:00:03.610023+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-24T00:00:03.610024+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-07-24T00:00:03.610026+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-07-24T00:00:04.345273+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-07-24T00:00:04.356753+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-07-24T00:00:09.963238+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vast-shore-9845.herokuapp.com request_id=822845f6-3908-4248-a575-814ca10d22d2 fwd="84.81.77.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-07-24T00:00:10.800435+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vast-shore-9845.herokuapp.com request_id=873c38e3-d55c-4645-8ac5-97422fa125bb fwd="84.81.77.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-07-24T00:03:43.594872+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vast-shore-9845.herokuapp.com request_id=16ab9874-71c4-48f4-9ce8-a20958396716 fwd="84.81.77.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-07-24T00:03:44.334194+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vast-shore-9845.herokuapp.com request_id=d21a4989-daab-4363-bcfc-a482c9977a41 fwd="84.81.77.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-07-24T00:06:37.583563+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vast-shore-9845.herokuapp.com request_id=f06c025a-ee76-4d4e-aa87-e2c9fa4ddf32 fwd="84.81.77.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-07-24T00:06:38.170649+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vast-shore-9845.herokuapp.com request_id=45c72e79-010e-48f5-8859-ff28a299e0ef fwd="84.81.77.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
WARNING: Toolbelt v3.40.6 update available.
```

Comment: double check that your gem file matches the tutorial's

Comment: i double checked and i am using the same gem file

Comment: Updated with new log

Comment: check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29594420/rails-tutorial-error-with-cloud-9

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually with the gem version 5.0.1 so just run:

```
bundle update sass-rails
```

which ultimately updates you `saas-rails` gem to the latest one. Or you can enter the version 5.0.2+ in your Gemfile like

```
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.3'
```